# IOException: Too many open files Thingsboard AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp, mqtt, thingsboard

We have hosted **TB in AWS** and We sending json data from GSM communication using **MQTT protocol** , for this we are using number of devices at the same time. but sometime we are getting error as **Too Many files open** on AWS log.

[image: Error log]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't post images of error messages, and if you must post images use the built in imgru system

Answer (score 1):

The too many open files error is normally because you have too many open sockets (Sockets consume file handles the same as open files).

In this case you have hit the maximum number of incoming client connections, which is probably the default 1024 limit.

The number of open files is controlled by ulimits on linux platforms, this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8945/how-can-i-increase-open-files-limit-for-all-processes) has details about how to change the limit.

Comment: Thank you. nunber of open file limit has been **183545** . In this path */proc/sys/fs/file-max*

Comment: If you have maxed out the limit and still hitting the error then you need to look at horizontal scaling to spread the load across multiple instances